# InfoPath Form Fails Intermittently

Tags: infopath, 2007

Has anyone experienced this?  I have an InfoPath form that I use as a Content Type for a SharePoint document library.  Two users submitted forms, yesterday, that cannot be opened.  Two users submitted forms, yesterday, that are working fine.  Older submissions for the last few months seem OK.  New submissions made today seem OK.  Does anyone have an idea how I could pinpoint this problem?

UPDATE: I went to one of the users whose form would not open.  I found that he had been sent an email with the URL to the form in question. When he clicked the URL to the online form, his PC opened InfoPath instead of opening the browser window.  Is there something I can do to prevent this problem?

Comment: Were there changes made to the form?  Schema changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I get errors as such I really get nothing from the details of the error that InfoPath gives as part of the details.  Have you took a look at the ULS logs and/or event viewer logs.  Try that.  How many controls do these forms have?  I have seen issues where this happens when there might be too many controls on the form.